# JFrame not updating with Background change

Tags: java, swing, jframe, handler, jcomponent

I created a class were bosex are displayed, and it reads where you click, and the handler changes the background color based on the location of you click, Everything works except for the updating of the JFrame. I tried 3 different lines of code, as shown in the handler. 
Code:

```
public class Dynamic_Bg_Color extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

JFrame frame;

Handler handler = new Handler();

static Dimension size = new Dimension(500,400);

public Dynamic_Bg_Color(){


    frame = new JFrame("BG Color Changer");

    frame = this;

    setBackground(Color.cyan);

    frame.addMouseListener(handler);

}

public void paint(Graphics g1){

    System.out.println("Click");

    Graphics g = (Graphics)g1;

    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(20,20,frame.getWidth()-40,100);

    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(20,140,frame.getWidth()-40,100);

    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.fillRect(20,260,frame.getWidth()-40,100);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Dynamic_Bg_Color d = new Dynamic_Bg_Color();

    d.frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size));
    d.frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(size));
    d.frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(size));
    d.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    d.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    d.frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    d.frame.setVisible(true);
}

public class Handler implements MouseListener{

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

        if(x>= 20 && x<=frame.getWidth()-40 && y>=20 && y<= 120){
            setBackground(Color.blue);
        }
        if(x>= 20 && x<=frame.getWidth()-40 && y>=140 && y<= 240){
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
        }
        if(x>= 20 && x<=frame.getWidth()-40 && y>=260 && y<= 360){
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.orange);
        }
        repaint();
    }

//Implemented Methods, cut to shorten, no code in them//

}

}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would extend from `JFrame` only to them ignore it and create second frame, then wonder why it won't paint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't override `paint` of top level containers.  They are responsible for maintaining a complex paint chain (which you have now broken) and they aren't double buffered which can result in flickering when painted.
2. Do call `super.paintXxx`.

Instead of extending `JFrame`, use `JPanel`.  Instead of overriding `paint`, override `paintComponent`.  Call `super.paintComponent` before you do any other custom painting.  It is responsible for painting the background

Finally, add this panel to a instance of `JFrame`...

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

**Updated with runnable example**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Dynamic_Bg_Color extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Dynamic_Bg_Color() {
        setBackground(Color.cyan);
        addMouseListener(new Handler());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        System.out.println("Click");

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(20, 20, getWidth() - 40, 100);

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(20, 140, getWidth() - 40, 100);

        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(20, 260, getWidth() - 40, 100);
    }

    public class Handler extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();

            System.out.println(x + "x" + y);

            if (x >= 20 && x <= getWidth() - 40 && y >= 20 && y <= 120) {
                setBackground(Color.blue);
            }
            if (x >= 20 && x <= getWidth() - 40 && y >= 140 && y <= 240) {
                setBackground(Color.green);
            }
            if (x >= 20 && x <= getWidth() - 40 && y >= 260 && y <= 360) {
                setBackground(Color.orange);
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                Dynamic_Bg_Color d = new Dynamic_Bg_Color();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(d);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: So i made it extend JPanel,and the other changes you said, except for the super.paintComponentXxx, im new to java and dont exactly know what that means. and i fixed a few erros, but now im back where i was 3 hours ago, a functioning program except the paintComponent() method  was not being called. The background color changes though, just no visual boxes that come from paintComponent(), thanks.

Comment: Updated with runnable example

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, this fixed the problem. I tried implementing this into my code, and it worked without a few things such as the whole EventQueue, but nonetheless, it worked, so thanks. I will try to upload final code when i can, it says i must wait.